# javascript window.print() access is denied

Tags: javascript, image, cross-domain

I'm loading an image from a different domain in a img html element via $.ajax cross domain call and opening up a popup with the contents of the image as you can see in the code below

```
     var printWindow= "";                                                                 
      methodName = "CreateVisitor";
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: visitorServiceUrl + methodName + "/" + tenantId + "/" + userId
                    + "/" + visitorid + "/" + visitorname + "/" + visitormobilenumber
                    + "/" + visitorcompanyid + "/" + visitorcompanyname + "/" + visiteeid,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    var imageUrl = "";
                    imageUrl = data ? siteImageUrl + data : 'image/NO_IMAGE.jpg';
                    $("#visitorcard").attr('src', imageUrl);
                    printWindow = window.open($("#visitorcard").attr('src'), "_blank", 'width=200,height=200');
                    //                        printWindow.onload = function () {
                    //                            printWindow.print();
                    //                        };
                    setTimeout(function () { printvisitorcard(); }, 1000);

                },
                error: function (xhr, type, exception) {
                    //alert("Error: " + xhr + " : " + exception + " : " + type);
                }
            });
```

I then use a setTimeout() to try to automatically print the image to my network printer (I'm not sure if I'm in the same domain or not) like this

```
function printvisitorcard() {
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
```

}

However each time I'm getting a **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied.** on the printWindow.print(); line.   I'm aware of cross domain issue with javascript but I still want to print the image. How do I overcome this error? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S
Firefox and Chrome do not throw this error however they also do not print the image.

Answer (score 1):

change to something from your own domain.

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/suVuk/show/) - works in Fx - to work in Chrome, you need to add a click handler. Popups are blocked unless the user clicked to get it

```
success: function (data) {
  var imageUrl = data ? siteImageUrl + data : 'image/NO_IMAGE.jpg';
  $("#visitorcard").attr('src', imageUrl);
  var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank", 'width=200,height=200');
  printWindow.document.write('<body onload="window.focus();window.print()">'+
    $("#visitorcard").parent().html()+'</body>');
  printWindow.document.close();
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mplungjan, however I'm still getting **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied** exception from javascript.

Comment: That sounds VERY strange. Does the window open and does it still work in Firefox with my suggestion? You do notice that your print function is no longer needed, right?

Comment: True, @mplungjan my print function is no longer needed. Yes window does popup with the image and no it does not print. It fails silently in Firefox and Chrome, while in IE it throws me the above said error.